# Selecting a value in select2 having optGroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm giving following data input to select2

```
data = [{
    "id": "all",
    "text": "All",
    "children": [{
        "id": "item1",
        "text": "item1"
    }, {
        "id": "item2",
        "text": "item2"
    }]
}];
```

and I'm initialising select2 as:

```
$(parent).select2({"data":data});
```

Now to select the value "**item1**", I did

```
$(parent).select2("val",["item1"]);
```

However instead of value "**item1**"  value "**all**" is getting selected. How to select value item1?

Comment: I think it's got something to do with the fact that item1 is child object, and it doesn't know

Comment: ooh ... but how to select the child object ? thanks ..

Comment: I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/platypusman/xDUUg/) that may help, you seem to have a similar object structure

Comment: Remove the "s" from `childrens`, it should be `children`.

Comment: yes my bad .. it is children.I have edited the same above .. thanks

Comment: @SterlingArcher fiddle not working :(

Comment: Selecting item1 works fine by me. Please post the entire function where you call `$(parent).select2("val",["item1"]);` from.

Comment: You example works for me. Take a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doMgry

Answer (score 7):

To set the selected value using `select2` you should use:

```
$(parent).val("item1").trigger("change");
```

From the [release notes](http://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-methods):

> You should directly call .val on the underlying element instead. If you needed the second parameter (triggerChange), you should also
>   call .trigger("change") on the element.
>
> ```
> $("select").val("1"); // instead of $("select").select2("val", "1");
> ```

Comment: But is this the right way to do it.I mean what is the difference between $(parent).select2('item1') and $(parent).val('item1').

Comment: The first method is still working but will be removed in the next release. And actually the second method is like for normal select. This way if you add the plugin to an existing code your js will be still working

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b0bod29/1/) where item1 is selected.

JS:

```
var data = [{
    id: 'all',
    text: 'All',
    children: [{
        id: 'item1',
        text: 'item1'
    }, {
        id: 'item2',
        text: 'item2'
    }]
}];

$('.js-example-data-array').select2({data:data});

$('.js-example-data-array').select2('val',['item1']);
```

HTML:

```
<select class="js-example-data-array">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean that the value "All" gets selected at start or if you want to select "item1" by code and it doesn't work. I find it strange that "All" gets selected as value since it should be treated as a category, even by adding

```
$(".select2-text").select2("val",["item1"]);
```

it won't select "All" for me. If i add

```
$(".select2-text").select2("val",["item2"]);
```

It will select "item2" for me (which means the method to select the item works, though it's not the best way, as stated in Lelio Faieta's Answer)

if i add

```
$(".select2-text").select2("val",["all"]);
```

it won't select "All" for me, it will just show me a blank select. So I think there must be an issue with your code because in a clean page there seems to be no way to select "All"

Can you show us the whole code, including the html of your page (at least the part relevant to the select). I have tried this (see plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/m6pFUt?p=preview )

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    data = [{
        "id": "all",
        "text": "All",
        "children": [{
            "id": "item1",
            "text": "item1"
        }, {
            "id": "item2",
            "text": "item2"
        }]
    }];

    $(".select2-text").select2({
        "data": data
    });
});
</script>
<select class="select2-text"></select>
```

And it starts with item1 selected, while "All" is treated as a category. So maybe it's just because something is wrong in your code/HTML.
What version of Select2 are you using? i'm using 2-4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/maluro/1/) to show you that it works. The demo, uses the `select` tag as a selector for an empty and existing `select` element. Indeed, I don't know what are you meaning by `parent`:

```
<select>
</select>
<script>
data = [{
    "id": "all",
    "text": "All",
    "children": [{
        "id": "item1",
        "text": "item1"
    }, {
        "id": "item2",
        "text": "item2"
    }]
}];

$('select').select2({
    "data": data
});

$('select').select2("val", ["item2"]);

</script>
```